# How can I setup a multi-item list with moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I'm trying to write a unit test for my method but failed. I want to return the list with the 2 item response of `GetMyRequest` with Mock(**package Moq**), then I run `Task.WhenAll` with the response returned with my method. So I used the `SetupSequence` method but it returned a single-item list. How can I return a multi-item list in my test.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    ProductService = new Mock<IProductService>();
    var myResponse = myStringList.Select(async x => await _myService.GetMyRequest(x, null, null)).ToList();

    //my response type -> List<Task<ResponseModel>>

    var myResponses = await Task.WhenAll(myResponse);
}
```

I want `myResponses` multi-item list with mocking but it single-item.

Unit tests

```
public async Task InitializeAsync(){
    ServiceResponse = Fixture.Build<MyModel>().CreateMany(2).ToList();
    MyService = new Mock<IProductService>();
    MyService.SetupSequence(service => service.GetMyRequest(It.IsAny<string>(), null, null))
                      .ReturnsAsync(ServiceResponse[0])
                      .ReturnsAsync(ServiceResponse[1]);
}
```

Comment: Can you replace var with the real type? For me myResponse  is not a list of Tasks as you suggest in the comment in code. You are awaiting the call so you should get a `List<ResponseModel>`. And since you awaited the calls there is no need for a `Task.WhenAll` since the Task are all completed and already gone. And the Task returned from `Task.WhenAll` isn't the result of the tasks its just a Task where you can check if all is completed. You would need to check back at `myResponse` for the result if that thing where a List of Tasks which it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR: You can't return multiple items for your `GetMyRequest`

---

`SetupSequence` means that you want to setup your `GetMyRequest` in a way that multiple calls against it will result with different responses.

- For the first call you will receive the value of `ServiceResponse[0]`
- For the second call you will receive the value of `ServiceResponse[1]`

According to my understanding the return type of `GetMyRequest` is `Task<ServiceResponse>` , that's why you can't define a mock to return `Task<IEnumerable<ServiceResponse>>` or something similar.

Comment: He calls it via a Linq Select statement so the single responses are collected into a List by that.

Comment: @Ralf Yes, I saw it. I tried to reflect only on the mocking part.